# MySQL: using an incremented variable inside an Update statement within a cursor

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, sql-update, scope

using MySQL 5.5, I am trying to update a decimal field with a value created from the combination of two other numbers, one is for the digits to the right of the decimal point, and the other is for the integer part of the number:

For example:
x=5, y=19, and Z= 5.19

However, the decimal part is actually an incremented variable. And I already set the SET statement to increment the variable but the update statement only sees its initial value.

Any ideas?
 Edit: here is the procedure where I am using the code(corrected according to answers):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE certNo DECIMAL(13,3);
DECLARE dups, ID INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE done INT default false;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT cert_id,certNum, COUNT(certNum) as Duplicates from migrate
GROUP BY certNum
HAVING Duplicates > 1;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 into ID, certNo, dups;
  IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; 
    END IF;
set @counter=0;
while @counter <= dups DO
    UPDATE migrate_cert_tblcert
    #SET certNum = CONCAT_WS('.',certNo,@duplis)
    SET certNum = cast(certNo + @counter/100 as decimal(10,2))
    WHERE certNum = certNo;

    SET @counter := @counter + 1;

SELECT certNo,@counter,cast(truncate(certNo,0) + @counter/100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) new;
END WHILE;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;
END
```

I noticed that now the code partially works, but the @counter incremented value doesn't go back to the update statement again! (the update statement only sees is as "1")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know beforehand the number of decimal places you will need. Otherwise, how would you know if `y=1` means `0.1` or `0.01` or `0.001` or...?

Once you have decided that, things become very simple:

```
set @decPos = 100; -- Asuming y "counts" hundreths
select x, y, cast(x + y / @decPos as decimal(8,2))
from yourTable;
```

Comment: you are right, and I know its will be hundreds. However, I even tried something like : SET Z=cast(x + 1/1000 as decimal(13,3)) but it still saves and shows Z in the expected format!

Comment: I found out that the problem was in the way of incrementing a variable inside update statement! now: I dropped the while-loop, I dropped the SET @counter, and replaced the "@counter/100" with "(@counter:=@counter+1)/100" ...and it worked !

Answer (score 2):

Concat then cast to the datatype

```
SELECT CAST(concat(concat(1, '.'), 2 ) AS DECIMAL(10,4) )
```

Or more simpler

```
SELECT 1 + 2/100
```

with cast

```
SELECT cast(1 + 2/100 as decimal(10,2))
```

Comment: but I thought concat() takes multiple paramaters and not just two. Could that be the reason its not working? Anyway, I managed to concat the numbers successfully as a string, but what never works is when I try to cast this string into a decimal type variable

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = CONCAT(5,'.',19);
```

Given MySQL's tendencies when it comes to implicit casting, I would expect that this -- somewhat counterintuitively -- is likely to be the cleanest solution, since doing division on your inputs could lead to imprecision. This generates a resulting string that "looks like" a decimal and it should (for that reason) be implicitly cast to the correct data type for the target column.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, sometimes its just simpler than one think!